# Acceptability of concessive parenthetical if clause

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, conditionals, that, dependent-clause

Is the following sentence correct?

> They might build a community that, if it could not change the depressing nature of the work, could at least make the workplace more bearable.

Is it okay to have the “it” in “…that, if it could not change…”?

Comment: Yes, except _that_ is not useable followed by a comma intonation. Use _which_ instead. The _it_ refers to the whole first clause and is perfectly grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

A more conventional organization might be:

> They might build a community that could at least make the workplace
> more bearable, **even** if it could not change the depressing nature
> of the work.

However, examples similar to the original are to be found without much effort, so it seems perfectly acceptable. The only difference being that in the original *if* has concessive meaning similar to *though* while the following are simply conditional.

> I say' fleetingly' because he doesn't dwell upon the shortcoming of a
> system that if it served some well, was subsidised by the taxes and
> opportunity of those below. ([Irish Examiner](https://www.irishexaminer.com/lifestyle/arid-20237450.html))
>
> The smoke grew heavier from first pitch to last, a trend that if it
> continues might put Friday's series opener against the Angels in
> doubt. ([Fan Nation](https://www.si.com/mlb/athletics/news/smoke-from-norcal-fires-cant-stop-athletics-from-beating-d-backs-again))
>
> Over the past few months, the onslaught of the Islamic State has
> wrought the systematic destruction of cultural artifacts from Palmyra
> to Nineva, all because they were deemed " offensive " by a minority
> that if it had its way, would ensure the entire world would adhere to
> a dark and revisionist existence. ([AL.com](http://www.al.com/opinion/index.ssf/2015/06/black_veteran_a_son_of_the_sou.html))

The above all have the ***it*** in, so yes, it is acceptable. In fact, it is required and would produce an ungrammatical result if removed.

The clause introduced by *if* is part of (or at least positioned within) the relative clause introduced by *that*, which has a relativized subject. This may be why you initially worried that *it* should be omitted; however the relativized element is the subject of the relative clause, not the subject of the subordinate clause introduced by *if* inside the relative clause, so *it* still needs to be included.

If there were a coordination in the relative clause of two instances of ***could***, having the same function in clause structure, then ***it*** could be omitted, as in:

> They might build a community that **could** not change the depressing
> nature of the work, but **could** at least make the workplace more
> bearable.

The difference being:

> They might build a community [that, if [it could not change the
> depressing nature of the work], could at least make the workplace more
> bearable.]
>
> They might build a community [that [[**could** not change the depressing
> nature of the work], [but **could** at least make the workplace more
> bearable.]]

Comment: Thank you for your suggested improvement as well! I have found examples as well like the ones you kindly provided, but repeating the subject by writing “it” feels wrong to me. I am no longer well-versed in grammatical theory or terminology, but my inclination is some rule is not followed.

Comment: @AnuraagGopaluni If it appears in a wide range of published materials produced by native speakers, then it is by definition grammatical. Don't fret too much over what some stickler with a style manual may say.

Comment: You’re definitely right there. I am just curious for edification purposes. One question about your response: I assume “community” is the “relativized subject” for the relative clause introduced by “that”, but the “it” inside the subordinate clause introduced by “if” refers to the same subject of “community”, no? It is this repetition that is still bothering me. I apologize if I am not understanding your response.

Comment: @AnuraagGopaluni There can only be one element relativized, and the subjects of the two respective clauses (one introduced by _that_ and one introduced by _if_) are two separate elements, even if they have the same referent. You surely wouldn't want to delete the _he_ in: _Tim is the only employee that showers before he goes home_. Further, repetition by itself is no reason to omit a subject, e.g. _I think I'll take a nap when I get home_. It would be possible in a coordination where all the verbs share a single subject equally - _Bob got up, ate, and went to work_.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "correct" means, but it is not a nice sentence. The whole thing is clunky. There's no way to read it that makes it sound good. And it takes too long to process, to understand.

Parenthetical portions are, if at all possible, normally surrounded by commas, not separated by them.

Having a comma before *that* seems very strange because you would not have a pause there used restrictively, and use non-restrictively you would want a comma-*which*, not a comma-*that*. You might want a *which* anyway.

Try this:

- They might build a community that could, if not *change* the work’s depressing nature, at least make the workplace where it takes place more bearable.

Comment: Thank you! I actually misplaced the comma originally—I meant to place it after “that”, not before. Your improvement makes perfect sentence to me. I still wonder, however, if having the “it” in “…that, if it…” breaks some grammatical rule.